# Cant change animation action from move to hit

Tags: animation

With blender an 3D artist made me an unit with 6 animations. When I downloaded the file I was able to change all animations. But now I cant. Even if I select the shield and after that I cant change animation to another.

My unit walks, but when I change animation to hit , it still walks. No idea how to fix it.

On my Dope Sheet I see "a collection of F curves for animation" with the namings "walk, stay, hit..". When i change them and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to start animation), it still walks, no matter what I do. I am weak in blender, forgot everything so long ago. And I try so many buttons, but still cant change the character to hit. Please help with suggestions (in noob talk please).

[image]

Comment: there'S something odd about that screenshot: Your camera seems to be the active object. That means, at the moment you are applying all the animation data to the camera. Now, since the camera does not have the bones which are animated in the action, nothing happens to it. Try this: Select the character and change the animations there. If that doesn't work, please post a screenshot of that condition, or upload the blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that you have some action strips stuck in NLA editor (thus not giving you an opportunity to change the action). Go to NLA editor (it's a panel type) and see if there is anything besides your desired action. In any case, try to remove any NLA layers/strips related to the armature.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx. It was NLA editor problem as i remember.

Comment: Ayyy, I'm glad I was able to help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some people may edit one animation to be something else like the OP, but find the above answer does not help them; particularly if you seem to be able to pose the character, but find it reverting to the old version when moving on the timeline.

For those people, Check your graph editor to ensure your curves aren't dotted, which means they are protected from editing. It's very easy to turn this on by accident when 'tabbing' into an action stored on a strip. If you use the NLA editor much, this can be very useful to keep in mind.

-S

Answer (score -1):

Since I'm not that good with blender, you probably shouldn't trust my answer that much, but I'll try to help anyways.

From what you wrote, I think you might need to better understand the concept of keyframing. If you don't, I'll save you some time and simply explain it now.

Simply put, keyframing is where you say, "At this time, I want this object to be at point A, and at this time, I want the same object to be at point B." Then, the computer patches in everything in the middle, creating an animation. Search up, "Blender keyframing tutorial" on youtube if you need more help.

Unless if I misunderstood your question, thats all the advice I can give you. Perhaps someone with better knowledge will come around and help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answer. But all animations are already made. I seen they all working properly. I just cant run another animation. Probably some setting is prohibited me to do it.

Answer (score -1):

first select your bone , activate pose mode than switch your animation in action editor. thank you